# Understanding set.seed() in R

Tags: r, seed

I am using R and I have some issues with replicating the output of the following:

```
mod1 <- glm(TVAR ~ .,data = df, family = "binomial")
y <- predict.glm(mod1)
```

due to its dependency on `set.seed()`.

I have some questions related to this?

- I am aware of the fact that if I preliminarily use `set.seed(123)` (or whatever other seed), the random generations will always start at the same level hence I will achieve a replicable result. Nevertheless, let's say that I want to reverse engineer the seed by starting from a good result and then retrieving the seed to replicate that good results the next time. In other words, let's assume that I run the same code `n` times without preliminarily setting a seed with the intention of finding the result that best fits me and then to retrieve the seed that was used. Would that be possible? It may sound like sort of cheating but it is indeed not, as I am just trying to pin down the results of the code on its seed-dependency, under the assumption that the overall idea behind the code is sensed and only needs to achieve a replicable status.
- Just for my understanding: a new seed is only used when I delete all the variables in the environment? In fact, if I run the same code more than once but without cleaning the environment, the results are the same, hence the same seed was used. I would appreciate some clarity on this.
- Lastly: is there a way to understand when a function is dependent on `set.seed()`? For instance, on the CRAN manual, I could not find any indication of this which seems to be a crucial issue.

Comment: “starting from a good result” is fundamentally misguided. If you don’t get good prediction results across many seeds, your “good result” is, in fact, a fluke. “finding the result that best fits me” is statistically invalid.

Comment: Sorry, I'm unclear why you believe an RNG would be involved in your example code. That's not the case and thus the random seed in not used. Also, it's (practically) impossible "to reverse engineer the seed" for any decent pseudo-RGN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your points in turn:

> Would [reverse engineering the seed from the result of a computation] be possible?

It depends on the actual random-number generator being used, but in general this is hard, because the state space of a good RNG is huge and you might have to search it exhaustively. Potentially this wouldn’t just take hours but *years*.

> a new seed is only used when I delete all the variables in the environment?

A new seed is used whenever you invoke `set.seed`. The actual current seed value is stored in the hidden variable `.Random.seed` in the global environment. However, removing the seed won’t make your last computation reproducible, since R re-initialises the value of that seed based on a non-deterministic value (in actual fact, the current operating system time).

> if I run the same code more than once but without cleaning the environment, the results are the same, hence the same seed was used.

No: consuming random values (by calling a stochastic function) *changes* the random seed. So running multiple computations in a row without cleaning the environment does *not* produce the same result. In fact, that would be *terrible*. You can see this easily yourself:

```
〉rnorm(1)
[1] -0.3156453
〉rnorm(1)
[1] 0.7345465
```

… clearly, two consecutive calls of a stochastic  function (here, `rnorm`) did *not* produce the same result, even though I didn’t clean the environment in between calls.

> is there a way to understand when a function is dependent on `set.seed()`?

You could set different random seeds, rerun the function, and see if the output changes.

Apart from that there is no general, straightforward way to do this. If the function does not document its dependency on `set.seed`, then your only recourse is to look carefully at the source code of the function (and all functions it calls in turn).

---

Bonus (as noted by Roland in the comments):

`glm` and `predict.glm` are *not* stochastic functions, and do *not* depend no `set.seed`.

Comment: "look carefully at the source code" needs to include compiled code (such as C, C++ or Fortran). It's easier to set different seeds and try if you get different results if you are unsure whether a function calls an RNG.

Comment: @Roland Hm, that’s a good idea actually. It might not always work (false negatives) but with sufficiently large outputs it’s quite a good indicator.

Answer (score 2):

@KonradRudolph gives a good answer here.  I'd just like to add one point to it:

There are *three* ways to set the random seed, and they are not the same:

- Using `set.seed(n)` sets it to an easily reproducible state.
- Calling any of the internal random number generators also changes it, in a deterministic but less predictable way.
- Saving it and restoring it later sets it to the earlier state.

In general, `set.seed()` can only output a tiny fraction of the possible values of the random seed, whereas calling the RNG should (eventually) cycle through all of them.  There are about `2^20000` different random seeds possible, but `set.seed()` can only create about `2^32` of them.  (Both of these numbers are over-estimates, but the ratio is about right.)

You can save and restore the `.Random.seed` variable, or call `set.seed(n)` to set the random seed to a known state.  The only feasible way to reproduce a particular state is to start in a known state and repeat the calls that led to the one you want.