# How to get current seed from current state in R?

Tags: r, random, mersenne-twister

How can I get the current seed from the current RNG state in R? For instance,

```
a <- 1987
set.seed(a) 
b <- .Random.seed
```

How can I retrieve a (i.e., 1987) from b? Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you can. Strongly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65881975/3358272. Why are you trying to retrieve the integer seed from the current state of the RNG?

Comment: not sure the point or if it is possible, but you can brute force it `s <- lapply(1:10000, function(x) {set.seed(x); .Random.seed}); which(sapply(s, identical, b))` or you could write a while loop to run longer